# Query sum LEFT JOIN not returning data

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to creating a query where I return a property name and a total of work orders opened for each property. However, I'm getting always null for the TotalWorkOrders even though I have work orders for the properties.

My query:

```
SELECT p.PropertyName, p.PropertyID,
   TotalWorkOrders
  FROM Properties p
  LEFT JOIN (
        Select
          PropertyID,
          SUM(1) AS TotalWorkOrders
        From WorkOrders
       Where WorkOrderComplete=1
       ) sums ON sums.PropertyID = p.PropertyID
 Where p.PropertyID in (Select PropertyID From Properties Where CompanyID = 290)
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: No GROUP BY in the subquery?

Comment: Thanks... A group by fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

You should probably add a GROUP BY inside the "sums" sub-query.